# Offline Bootstrap jquery error when trying to use Wells in bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys can someone help me. with the jquery file that without having to go online for Googleapis,that will make my bootstrap well work correctly when its entirely offline... am trying to activate a notifications if successfull message so that the user may cancel bt the cancel b"X" isn't working.... Below is a link to my project files kindly have a look 
[Bootstrap project files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4m8xDULhMg4Y0NidnRCN3gzZGc)

Comment: Please add your code here not on drive.

Comment: how do i post code my friend

Comment: You can edit your question and paste your code directly. 
But paste code which is only related to YOUR PROBLEM.

Comment: I think you are getting error because of your Jquery version. Use newer

Comment: @Phantom am getting my code is not properly formatted when i paste it... indenting something helo

Comment: Please see this... Help...[How to ask Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Phantom hey???

Comment: just paste code...someone will modify it for you...

Comment: Phantom have tried pasting imagine its refusing for me to proceed

Comment: have you seen it.... do you mind giving me your WhatsApp number or any instant messenger u have i sent you the code easily

Comment: I got your code from drive. and I not able reproduce you error of well.
It is running fine with latest offline JQUERY also.

Comment: yeees everything is okay why don't you try pressing the "X" icon for cancelling the notification you will see it doesn't respond

Answer (score 0):

You have made spelling mistake that's why it is not closing the 'ALERT'

HERE:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dissmiss="alert" aria-label="close" >&times;</a>Don't forget Ramsey's Birthday
</div>
```

Mistake:

```
data-dissmiss="alert" // DISMISS
```

not `DISSMISS`

Use This:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" >&times;</a>Don't forget Ramsey's Birthday
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much.. i almost gave up on bootstrap ur the best king of programmers..... pliz show me where  i can vote for you to get more rankings you have now made me a millionaire in my country

Comment: Welcome...!!
you may see 'UP' and 'DOWN' button before answers. they are 'UP' and 'DOWN' Vote.

Comment: Thank you again it's because of you i have got my first pay check as a programmer... which platform are you active most frequently so. that i. may contact you whenever i have an issue

Comment: Thank you again it's because of you i have got my first pay check as a programmer... which platform are you active most frequently so. that i. may contact you whenever i have an issue

Comment: CSS, JS, AngularJS, PHP, Laravel, JQuery...
All are here to help each other on SO. Thank You, and feel free to ask question if you having an issue after you tried something.;)

Comment: hey # phantom i have another error whenever i try creating sidebar

Comment: trying to create a Toggle Menu

have 2 error first one says "loading failed for the <script > with source" http://loaclahost.1627/bootstrap/js/jquery. js". 

the second one is 
loading failed for the <script > with source" http://loaclahost.1627/bootstrap/js/jquery. min". 

all my offline js files are properly arranged as  required

Comment: i have posted my html and css source code in the continue answer section

Comment: have you typed correct spelling of 'localhost'? and is url correct?